# What's 'this' in IE's attachEvent

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I'm tired of writing jQuery, so I decide to learn some raw JavaScript.
Something in IE's `attachEvent` confused me. Here's the code:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    
btn.onclick = function(){
   alert(window.event.srcElement === this); //true, I know why.
};
        
btn.attachEvent('onclick', function(event){
   alert(event.srcElement === this); //fasle, but why?
});
```

I try to use IE's built-in debug tools, but it just told me that 'this' is an object, but nothing more...
so what's 'this' in  IE's `attachEvent`?

Comment: try outputting `this` to the console and see. use `console.log(this)`

Comment: I try that, but IE just told me it's an object, nothing more.

Comment: did you spot the typo "srcElemnt"? Without the "e" that event property will be undefined (and !== this).

Comment: just a typo, fixed.still return false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within an event handler bound by the IE-specific `attachEvent` method, `this` refers to the global `window` object:

```
btn.attachEvent('onclick', function(event) {
    alert(this === window); // true
}
```

In contrast, within an event handler bound by the standard `addEventListener` method, `this` refers to the DOM element from which the event handler was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

this is a context reference and is referencing window when the the click event occurs, because that is the only context that exists at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think U misspell one word.

```
    btn.attachEvent('onclick', function(event){
            alert(event.**srcElement** === this);
    });
```

And I tested the corresponding function addEventListener in chrome and ff, they both returned true.

IE do returns false.  Maybe because IE deal with btn.onclick=fn; and btn.attachEvent() with different way. IE passes global value(window) to the btn.attachEvent() method. You can test **this=== window** , it returns true.

Any comments about it?